# Domain Driven Design

Tags: domain-driven-design

I'm looking for clarification on the following 2 points with regards to DDD.

1.Can a domain entity call a repository?

2.Can a domain service call a repository?

Thanks

Edit

Found a suite of documents that detailed the DDD layers in lots of detail and this is what it said;

**Additionally, and although as a rule Repositories are only used from the Application layer, it is also possible to make exceptions, and make queries invoking Repositories from the Domain services as necessary. But this should be avoided as much as possible in order to achieve homogeneity in our developments.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't design a domain entity to reference a repository. A "repository" is rarely a part of the domain and would introduce a technical concern into your domain model. I've found repositories to fit best at the application services layer.

Comment: Thanks for your response. What about a domain service?

Comment: David, I tend to think that any service that needs a repository is probably an application service.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of such hard and fast rules.  *Anything* can be done.

But here's how I do it.  I don't know if it qualifies as DDD:

1. Usually domain objects do not call repositories.  They need not be aware whether they are persisted or not.
2. Services orchestrate domain objects and repositories to fulfill use cases.  They own units of work and manage transactions.

Comment: Your point 1 is the way I view things wrt domain objects, however on your point 2 when you talk about services are you talking specifically about application services? If so what about domain services?

Comment: Eric Evans DDD architecture suggests the following layering scheme, UI, Application, Domain and Infrastructure each have their own distinct responsibility within DDD. Services can exist in all these layers for differing reasons. What you suggested seems what Eric describes as the Application Layer. The Domain Layer is where your domain objects and services live, and I'm just not sure that a domain service should actually make use of repository interfaces, although in my head I dont see why they wouldn't otherwise it would push a lot of domain concerns into the application layer.

Comment: Too much nomenclature.  Smacks of dogma.  I liked the book a lot, but it could have used a better editor.  And I don't know that it's set the world on fire.